# Как правильно проверить :hover в Safari?

Tags: jquery, safari

В небольшом приложении проверяю находится ли курсор над данным объектом. В хроме и файерфоксе нормально работает проверка вида `if($(this).is(":hover"))`, но в сафари этот код всегда возвращает `false`.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как решить этот нюанс?

Comment: думаю, в случае с Сафари следует указывать версию браузера. Ибо актуальный Сафари на Маках и древний Сафари для Виндоус - две большие разницы

Comment: тоже хотел бы знать, но к сожалению не владею информацией. есть подозрение что у некоторых макоюзеров могут стоять и старые версии сафари

Answer (score 1):

Существует альтернатива в виде событий `mouseover` и `mouseleave`, которые прекрасно работают в Safari (5.1.7 для Windows). Вот пример:

```js
$('.test').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#eee');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'></div>
```

[Пример на JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/sohoyesogo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Еще почитайте статью: "[Мышь: движение mouseover/out, mouseenter/leave](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave)".
Она поможет лучше разобраться с этими событиями.

Comment: "но ведь jquery кроссбраузерный". Видимо надо багрепорт к ним написать на эту тему

Comment: спасибо за подсказку. не подумал что можно написать багрепорт. по идее это как раз задача джиквери обеспечивать кроссбраузерность